# Paginate through instagram responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

In my webapp I would like to load photos with a specific tag from instagram. I get the first page of results, but if I try to receive the next page with the pagination.next_url command I end up with the same results as before. 
My code:

```
url="https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/vienna/media/recent?client_id=9c6380addbe14f42bf1e992acae243f2&callback=?";      

        $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
            $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
                var filter = item.filter;
                var instaLink = item.link;
                $('#footer').append(filter,'<br />');           
                jQuery("<a />").attr("href", instaLink).appendTo("#footer").text(instaLink).after("<br />"); 
            }); 
            url = data.pagination.next_url;
            console.log(window.url);
    });
```

I am a beginner concerning javascript and jQuery, but I think the url variable is not set properly. Because when I want to call the $getJSON(url,function(...){} again the result is the same.

Comment: share full function code; not just this calling what the actual function and how you are calling it;

Answer (score 0):

It is a scope issue. url variable is local one inside your closure.
try to declare your url variable with a different name. (use var keyword ...)

But to be able to loop through all the results, that will not help so much. You have to do it recursively until data.pagination.next_url is not returned back by the instagram api.